# cPanel redirecting some subdomains to defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: apache, cpanel

I'm not really sure what's going on here.

We have a main domain and 5 parked domains.

We added a subdomain for each of the 5 parked domains to point to the same home location; `/home/main_domain/public_html/sub`

Three of the five subdomains work without issue. The other two return the default website cgi.

We initially created the subdomains last week. So I feel that time isn't the issue.

Things I've tried:

- cleared the cache many times
- switched browsers.
- used incognito mode
- used curl
- deleted and recreated the subdomains numerous times
- deleted all of the non-working subdomains and added them one at a time
- removed everything in my `.htaccess` file
- flushed my dns (windows 10)

It really puzzles me that only 2 of the 5 are having issues. I'm running out of ideas here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Ok so I just used the "Track DNS" tool in cPanel and found that the two subdomains that aren't working have a different ip than the other three. I'm still investigating *why* that is though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the two parked domains had an old IP being used for their A records.